# Fading CAShapeLayer path appearance

Tags: ios, core-animation, fade, cashapelayer

I have an issue with showing a CAShapeLayer onto a CALayer.

Here is what I try to achieve:

[image]
[image]

I have an overlay over my view, I make a hole in the overlay so I can reveal what's behind. This works fine.

Now I want to be able to animate the creation of the hole. I'd like to have the hole part fading from the overlay color to transparent.

I already tried drawing another shape over the hole and make it disappear, it works, but this is not perfect as you can see in the last image (I can make it less visible, but still, it is not enough), and I don't think this is the correct way to do it.

[image]

If you have any idea or advice!

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'd really like to know how you made the hole in the overlay :)

Comment: @ØyvindHauge have a look here: https://gist.github.com/StrAbZ/13e47dabd0cb4a6a22f3#file-gistfile1-m